# MonitorFromWindow(DefaultToNearest) doesn't work during drag

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

I'm using the Windows API method `MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST)` as part of some overridden maximize functionality in my WPF application. One issue we've had with it is that the "nearest" window does not updating during drag operations (triggered by `DragMove` on the Window instance).

Suppose you drag the window between two screens of differing resolution and trigger the Aero Snap functionality on the second screen. This triggers a query on the window size (message `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`). Using `MonitorFromWindow` in this scenario returns the wrong screen. It's as if the data used by `MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST` is not updated until the drag operation completes, and that doesn't complete until the resize function triggered by the Aero Snap completes. Is there some way to flush the current window position before answering the `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` query?

Comment: `MonitorFromWindow` is using `MonitorFromRect` internally. Instead of having window properties updated, you can simply use the other function against the coordinates of interest directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since snapping is based on the mouse position, a solution to the problem would be to use [`GetCursorPos`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648390.aspx) to get the current mouse position. Then pass that point to [`MonitorFromPoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145062.aspx) to obtain the handle for the monitor that currently contains the mouse pointer.

A simple example:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Point lpPoint);

public const int MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST = 2;

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr MonitorFromPoint(Point pt, UInt32 dwFlags);

public IntPtr GetCurrentMonitor()
{
    Point p = new Point(0,0);
    if (!GetCursorPos(ref p))
    {
        // Decide what to do here.
    }
    IntPtr hMonitor = MonitorFromPoint(p, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
    // validate hMonitor
    return hMonitor;
}
```